# How do I access the value of a variable in PuLP?

Tags: python, pulp

In Python's `PuLP` package, how can I get the value of a decision variable?

For example, if I declare a variable—

```
x = LpVariable('x_var', cat=LpContinuous)
```

—then solve the problem, then use

```
print(x)
```

Python just outputs:

```
x_var
```

How can I get the value of the variable, not its name?

Comment: This is another question that I've answered a few times on SO and other sites, so I figured I'd post a Q&A here.

Answer (score 12):

To get the *value* of the decision variable, you need to use the `varValue` property of the `LpVariable`, so:

```
print(x.varValue)
```

You can also use:

```
print(x.value())
```

The explanation is that the Python variable `x` is not the decision variable itself, it is a `PuLP` object of type `LpVariable`:

```
In[5]: type(x)
Out[5]: pulp.pulp.LpVariable
```

Therefore, just using `print(x)` does not give you the value of the decision variable, it gives you the variable name that you supplied in the `name` argument when you declared your `LpVariable`. (In particular, Python is printing the string returned by the `LpVariable`'s `__repr__` function, which is just the `name`.)

---

You can also access the name of a variable using the `name` property. This is also convenient for listing all of the variables at once:

```
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

---

Here's a more complete example, using Hillier and Lieberman's (in)famous "Wyndor Glass" model:

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem('glass', LpMaximize)

# Declare variables.
x1 = LpVariable('x1_var', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)
x2 = LpVariable('x2_var', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)

# Build objective function.
prob += 3 * x1 + 5 * x2

# Add constraints.    
prob += x1 <= 4
prob += 2 * x2 <= 12
prob += 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 <= 18

# Solve problem.
prob.solve()

# Print status.
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status], "\n")

print("The value of x1 = {}. (Not what we want.)".format(x1))
print("The values of x1.value() and x1.varValue = {} and {}. (That's what we want.)\n".format(x1.value(), x1.varValue))

# Print optimal values of decision variables.
print("All variables:")
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

The output is:

```
Status: Optimal 

The value of x1 = x1_var. (Not what we want.)
The values of x1.value() and x1.varValue = 2.0 and 2.0. (That's what we want.)

All variables:
x1_var = 2.0
x2_var = 6.0
```

Note that the idea is the same if we declare the variables using `LpVariable.dicts`, e.g.:

```
x = LpVariable.dicts('x_var', range(1, 3), lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)

prob += 3 * x[1] + 5 * x[2]

(etc.)
```

Then `print(x[1])` gives

```
x_var_1
```

and `print(x[1].varValue)` gives

```
2.0
```